# How to display a floating icon on mapview?

Tags: android

I would like to display an icon in mapview just like the "change to list view icon" displayed on Google Places program. any clue how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to put an icon in a relative place of the screen you can merge the mapview with a relative layout (in the XML page) some thing like this:

```
<merge
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="xxxxxxxxxx" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon">
    </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

Or if you need to use an icon over a map coordinate that you specify then you need to define an overlay.

hope this helps :)

Comment: Happy to help :) if the answer solved your problem don't forget to accept it XD

Comment: I tried it but the button didn't show up ... noitce I didn't use "mergae", is it required to use it? .. any clue why button didn't show up?

Comment: Merge is the all point, it allows you to put the relative layout components (image buttons) on top of your map. Please post your xml code so that I can take a look at it and help you :)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called an Overlay. Check out the [Google Map View tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) under Part 2.

Comment: The issue with Overlay it moves with the map as user move the map. I need it to be fixed.